# python open textfile wih pandas getting error

Tags: python, pandas

A simple code to open a text file with pandas module as published a lot here in the Forum

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('list.txt', sep=" ", header=None)
data.columns = ["a", "b", "c", "etc."]
print(data)
```

but I get an error message related to  JSON.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/robert/Python/MPC_data/comet_pandas.py", line 1, in 
> import pandas as pd
> File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/**init**.py", line 183, in 
> v = get_versions()
> File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/_version.py", line 23, in get_versions
> return json.loads(version_json)
> AttributeError: module 'json' has no attribute 'loads'

> CJ95O010  1997 03 29.6644  0.913593  0.994932  130.6195  283.3707   88.9855  20200514  -2.0  4.0  C/1995 O1 (Hale-Bopp)                                    MPC106342
> PJ96R020  2019 02 11.5155  2.589984  0.313869  333.2955   40.0430    2.6004  20200514  11.5  4.0  P/1996 R2 (Lagerkvist)                                   NK   1615
> PJ97B010  2022 03 28.8307  2.054229  0.760061  183.3862  328.8921   12.3403  20200514  15.0  2.0  P/1997 B1 (Kobayashi)                                    MPC 30063
> PJ98V24S  2018 01 18.0487  3.435537  0.241739  244.7371  159.0301    5.0243  20200514  13.0  2.0  P/1998 VS24 (LINEAR)                                     MPC 75703
> PJ99R28O  2019 06 26.0365  1.124239  0.671921  231.2769  137.8823    7.5658  20200514  20.0  2.0  P/1999 RO28 (LONEOS)                                     NK    731

Any idea?

Comment: Can you include a few rows from `list.txt` ?

Answer (score -1):

There is a problem with importing Pandas package in line 1. So please try to uninstall package:
`pip uninstall pandas`

Then reinstall and run the code.
`pip install pandas`

Comment: I did your recommendation but I get still the same error.

Comment: Can you please share a chunk of your text file?

Answer (score -1):

It works

[image]

I deleted `data.columns = ["a", "b", "c"] and sep = " "`

It was the formatting of the text file